# How to display the most Recent/Latest Value in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi

My table looks something like this:

| Location | TimeSlot | Mean Rate | Max Rate | Min Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| New york | 2021-12-26 12:45:00 | 20.20 | 18.00 | 13.00 |
| New york | 2021-12-26 12:30:00 | 34.20 | 23.00 | 34.45 |
| New york | 2021-12-26 12:15:00 | 38.20 | 38.00 | 13.10 |
| New york | 2021-12-26 12:00:00 | 20.20 | 18.20 | 13.00 |
| Chicago | 2021-12-26 12:45:00 | 4.20 | 40.00 | 13.00 |
| Chicago | 2021-12-26 12:30:00 | 30.20 | 45.00 | 4.00 |

I want to create a table in powerbi that shows the most recent(latest) data point for a given location. For example in this case, the max rate in newyork would display 18.00.

Ive tried many solutions like the link below but they seem to display the maxx value which would be 38.00 for newyork,  45.00 for chicago etc, so now Im stuck!

Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you.

https://blog.enterprisedna.co/using-the-maxx-dax-function-in-power-bi-to-calculate-recent-values-in-your-data/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this **measure**:

```
Most Recent Max Rate =
VAR ThisLocation =
    MIN( Table1[Location] )
VAR LatestTimeSlot =
    CALCULATE(
        MAX( Table1[TimeSlot] ),
        Table1[Location] = ThisLocation
    )
VAR LatestMaxRate =
    LOOKUPVALUE(
        Table1[Max Rate],
        Table1[Location], ThisLocation,
        Table1[TimeSlot], LatestTimeSlot
    )
RETURN
    LatestMaxRate
```

which can be used alongside the *Location* field in, for example, a simple Table visual.